# Posting to User Social Stream, LinkedIn API with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, post, linkedin-api

I am trying to send a POST request to the LinkedIn Share API to post to the User's Social Stream. I already have the user's permission to post to his/her account.

I was wondering how do I structure my POST request to this URL:

http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares

What values do I need to POST? How do I post the user's Auth code?

I have the user's auth code saved as a local storage variable. My application is wrapped in a Phonegap iOS application.

Thanks for your help!

Let me know if you need me to clarify anything. Here is the [LinkedIn documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api).

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-linkedin

I tried [How to share text message in LinkedIn wall in PhoneGap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598851/how-to-share-text-message-in-linkedin-wall-in-phonegap) but was not success.