# how to post data to linked in wall using phonegap android?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I'm working on phonegap android application in which I need to post the data to linked in wall in the application.

I'm following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598851/how-to-share-text-message-in-linkedin-wall-in-phonegap?answertab=oldest), but it's not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var ref = window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=ntvp5q9iyw8g&scope=w_messages r_network rw_nus r_fullprofile&state=oYyw8xjqR7MLYmYq&redirect_uri=http://oauth://linkedin','_blank','location=no');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(e){
    $.mobile.loading( 'show' );
    if(e.url.indexOf('?code=') >=0 ){
        if(e.url.match(/=[^]+&/)){
            var code = e.url.match(/=[^]+&/)[0].substring(1).replace('&','');
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('code', code);
            ref.close();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code='+code+'&redirect_uri=http://oauth://linkedin&client_id=ntvp5q9iyw8g&client_secret=oYyw8xjqR7MLYmYq',
                success: function(a){

                    $.ajax({
                        url : 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?oauth2_access_token='+a.access_token,
                        type: 'post',
                        headers : {
                            'Content-Type'  : 'application/json',
                            'x-li-format'   : 'json',
                            'scope'         : 'rw_nus'  
                        },
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                          "recipients": {
                            "values": [
                            {
                              "person": {
                                "_path": "/people/~",
                               }
                            }]
                          },
                          "subject": "asdasdasd on your new position.",
                          "body": "You are certainly the best person for the job!"
                        }),
                        success: function(a){
                            alert(2222)
                        },
                        error: function(a){
                            alert(JSON.stringify(a))
                        }
                    })
                },
                error: function(a){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(a))
                }
            })
        }
    }
});

});
```

Comment: Tell us more about what happens when you try using the code in the link you posted.

Comment: Don't put this in the comment. Edit your question, and add your code & explanations.

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure you should replace the "xxxxxxx"s by the actual user_id and client_secret values.

Comment: And that still doesn't work ?

Comment: Are there any log messages you can post?

Comment: 04-27 09:29:11.085: V/browser(29934): onReceive : info.isAvailable() - true
04-27 09:29:11.249: V/browser(29934): BrowserActivity.onPageStarted: url = http://oauth//linkedin?code=AQRHJETEy1RcM0X0GgCBGb8yhtOHVB9AG5tksUrAlICxRDV68Kmq1XIqi8g5cooa9Br4jixzfXO38QYcHmRcNRQKTwJ8-BBPM7WBKpfpi-ZYQffpUK4&state=oYyw8xjqR7MLYmYq

Comment: After changing the redirect url to http://linkedin.com i am getting the log values like this,

04-27 09:58:02.128: V/browser(29934): BrowserActivity.onPageStarted: url = https://touch.www.linkedin.com/?sessionid=2313147178287104&rs=false#home
04-27 09:58:02.151: V/browser(29934): BrowserActivity.shouldOverrideUrlLoading: url = https://touch.www.linkedin.com/?sessionid=2313147178287104&rs=false#home webview = android.webkit.WebView@47d01538